# Когда следует размещать сайт в интернете?

Tags: хостинг

Подскажите, пожалуйста, когда созданный сайт лучше всего размещать в интернете? Когда уже работает весь функционал, мобильная версия, он максимально наполнен контентом и т. п.? Или можно постепенно это совершенствовать, будучи уже размещённым в инете?

Answer (score 1):

(На всякий случай: сайты, выполненные на онлайн-конструкторах вроде [a5](http://www.a5.ru/) или [uKit](https://ukit.com/ru), размещаются сразу с момента создания, незаполненными, следовательно, для них данный вопрос не имеет смысла. Также ответ составлен исходя из предположения, что у ув-мого ТС-а не сложный сайт с завышенными требованиями к хостингу.)

В общем случае **чем раньше, тем лучше**. Изменять, совершенствовать контент впоследствии сможете тогда, когда пожелаете.

Если сайт первый для Вас, лучше особо не медлить. В процессе работы над ним заодно происходит ознакомление со спецификой, преимуществами и проблемами, характерными именно для интернета, а не локального сервера, как то основам продвижения или обеспечением безопасности сайта.

И пусть размещённый в сети сайт «сырой», «недоделанный» — ничего страшного не приключится, но приступать к *раскрутке* следует тогда, когда он станет уже более-менее готовым.

Единственная значительная проблема — придётся платить. И если доменное имя (желательно его побыстрее занять, пока вас не опередили — ещё один довод к быстрому размещению) обходится лично для меня всего в 150 рублей в год, то цены за услуги хостингового провайдера могут и ударить по карману.

Какой у Вас сайт, статический или динамический? Используются ли, к примеру, php, MySQL?

Статическим подойдёт бесплатный хостинг сайтов [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) или его альтернативы. [Размещение сайта](http://isizov.ru/github-kak-hosting-dlya-sajtov/), [привязка домена](http://isizov.ru/kak-dobavit-domen-k-github-pages/). Требуются [базовые навыки обращения с Git](http://isizov.ru/kak-dobavit-domen-k-github-pages/).

Если динамический, то каковы Ваши требования к хостингу, сколько по предварительным расчётам придётся за него платить? Заявку на свободное размещение (только полезных) сайтов можно оставить, например, у [Oxnull](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/intl/ru/ch02.html). Если там не примут, а Вам хочется именно бесплатный хостинг, попробуйте выбрать из вариантов на [этом ресурсе](http://oxnull.net/invite.html) или [вот тут](http://freehostsfinder.com/ftp-support-hosting.php), только учтите, что пользоваться ими подчас одно мучение. Поэтому если не получилось с Oxnull'ом, лучше поискать варианты среди дешёвых HSP: при выборе прежде всего обращайте внимание на независимые отзывы, а не рекламные заверения.

Спасибо.